# Astarisk Call File_Can wait or get response to start playback?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

```
Channel: $number
Application: Playback
Data: $outputfilename
```

When callee answers the phone, s/he misses the first one or two words. So I would like to wait untill s/he gives any response like "hello?' or "alo" and then start playback. Is there anyway to make it done in the call file?

If there is not at least I would like to wait 1 or 2 seconds. Does wait(2) works here?

Comment: You can add on top of your dialplan wait command.

Comment: Can't I do it in the call file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Channel: $number
Application: Playback
Data: beep&silence/2&$outputfilename
```

That way it will play beep, which probably will be not heared by human, but for sure will start rtp process. After that 2 second wait(silence file) which may be required for echocancel training or connection process. That way you message will go clear.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Case closed :)

Comment: And I have a quick question, can we increase the volume of the playback in cal file?

Comment: You should use sox or any similar utility and increase volume in file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new dialplan context. In it You add Wait application and then Palyback. In call file you can connect number to this new context by specifying it directly or dialing to it via Dial(Local/XXX@new-context)

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is the RTP stream not being fully "up".  Until the call is established, RTP (sound) isn't shipped.  So, if you "start talking" right away, you loose words.  This is a dialplan side problem, because it depends on both ends of the call being in the "shipping sound" phase.

Using `Answer() ; Wait()` will not always fix this issue on VoIP connections, because it doesn't actually get the audio stream moving.  `Wait()` is more for cranky T1 lines with slow set-up speeds where you are literally waiting for the rest of the hardware to catch up.

You can get around this by just playing 1 or 2 seconds (1 works 80% of the time) of silence.  Eg:

```
[answering_context]
exten => s,1,Verbose(2,Example of good audio discipline)
 same => n, Playback(silence/1)
 same => n, Playback(the_real_message_you_want_to_send)
```

"Silence" is technically "still sound", but the human can't tell if you are shedding packets or clipping words during "silence".  By the time the `the_real_message_you_want_to_send` gets played, the audio stream will be fully stable.

Cheers!

Comment: Although your way is a good idea, I can't make dialplan or change extensions. Therefore arheops' answer is more useful for me.